# Sum of squares with Schnirelman's theorem, prove that there exists $k$ that $\forall n$ can be expressed as a sum of at most $k $ squares.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

By Fermat's sum of sqaure theorem $p=4k+1,\text{ }\exists k\Longleftrightarrow p=a^2+b^2$
$$\sum_{a^2+b^2= n\le x} 1 \ge \sum_{p=a^2+b^2\le x} 1 \gg \dfrac{x}{\log x}$$
and we have $$\sum_{n=a^2\le x}1=\sqrt{x}+O(1)$$
Therefore, for some $0<\delta<1$ $$\sum_{n=a^2+b^2+c^2\le x}1 \ge \left(\sum_{n=a^2+b^2\le x-x^\delta}1\right)\left(\sum_{n=a^2\le x^\delta} 1\right)\gg \dfrac{x}{\log x}\cdot x^{\delta/2}\gg x $$
By Scnhirelman's theorem, we obtain that any natural number can be expressed as a sum of at most $k$ squares, for some constant $k$.

Is it possible to conclude like this?

Comment: It's a classical fact that we can take $k = 4$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem

Comment: Sorry I want to ask whether it is possible to conclude like this? I have heard about the theorem and try to prove this result.

Answer (score 2):

This argument is not correct. Specifically, the first inequality in the last equation is not correct, because a number can be written as a sum-of-two-squares plus a square in many different ways. A more blatant form of the same error is the claim that the number of integers up to $x$ that can be written as the sum of two integers is
$$
\sum_{n=a+b\le x} 1 \ge \bigg( \sum_{a\le x/2} 1 \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{b\le x/2} 1 \bigg) \gg x^2,
$$
which is clearly false since the left-hand side is at most $x$. (Indeed, note that your last equation actually proposes to prove that the number of sums-of-three-squares up to $x$ is $\gg x^{1+\delta/2}$ for some $\delta>0$, which is certainly false.)

Comment: Let $\mathscr S_3 = \left\{a^2+b^2+c^2\right\}$ and $\mathscr S_1,\mathscr S_2$ to be the set of the sums of $1,2$ squares respectively. In addition, $\mathscr A(x)=\#\left\{n\le x : n\in\mathscr A\right\}$. If I modify the argument to be, let $s(n)$ be the number of ways that $n$ can be expressed as a sum of $3$ squares, we then can imply that $\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ n\in\mathscr S_3}}s(n) \ge\mathscr S_2(x-x^\delta)\cdot\mathscr S_1(x^\delta)$ ?

Comment: Definitely; but counting such integers weighted by the number of representations is a different question (and, in this case, known to be easier due to decompositions of the sort you describe).